# Prevent Crystal Reports to select related fields to get only distinct items

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports 14 with an Oracle DB. If I have related tables `Authors` and `Books` and I selects all the authors that have book with 'code' in their title Crystal will put `Books.title` in the SQL `SELECT` clause, even if I don't use any `Books` fields anywhere in the report (except for the record selection). The query looks like this:

```
SELECT "AUTHORS"."NAME", "BOOKS"."TITLE"
FROM "AUTHORS" INNER JOIN "BOOKS" ON "AUTHORS"."ID"="BOOKS"."AUTHOR"
WHERE "BOOKS"."TITLE" LIKE '%code%'
```

This causes a problem because, even if I use the "Distinct" option, I will get many entries for each author (if they have more then one book with 'code' in the title). But what I want is only one entry by author. "Distinct" do not work here because each entry is really distinct, their book title are different.

How can I avoid getting `"BOOKS"."TITLE"` in the `SELECT` clause like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "AUTHORS"."NAME"
FROM "AUTHORS" INNER JOIN "BOOKS" ON "AUTHORS"."ID"="BOOKS"."AUTHOR"
WHERE "BOOKS"."TITLE" LIKE '%code%'
```

If that's not possible, what's the best workaround to get distinct authors in my scenario?

**UPDATE**

I should add that currently I'm using this formula in the Suppress details section:

```
{AUTHORS.ID} = previous({AUTHORS.ID})
```

The problem with this solution and also the group solution proposed by @Beth is that the query is the same and the DB return too much data for no reason. In both solutions the data is filtered/regrouped in Crystal Reports, not in the DB.

Comment: What's wrong with using your second query as the data source?

Comment: I don't think I can use SQL directly because I'm using dynamic parameters coming from a prompt (so enter by the user). I am right? I'm new to Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 0):

can you group by authors in your report and suppress the `books.title` details?

to group by author, in your report, under the `Insert` menu, select '`Group...`' then select author.id in the first combo box and click OK.  You'll notice your report has changed to introduce Group Header and Footer sections above and below the detail section.  You can suppress the detail section and only the authors will print.

If you want only the authors to come across, you'll need to use a command sent to the data source with the SQL you want used, instead of using the tables directly like you are now.

You can create a command as your back-end with your parameter in it.  You'll use that parameterized command instead of the tables you're using now.  Try creating the command without the parameter first, then after you get that working, you can add your existing parameter into the command SQL.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I should group by authors? And I would like to know if this kind of grouping will be executed in the SQL query (with a distinct, etc.) or in Crystal Reports directly (meaning that duplicated authors row data will be send to Crystal and Crystal will regroup them)?

Comment: I tried before using groups but I wasn't understanding them completely. After your suggestion I retried and it works (I needed to move my stuff from Details to the Group Header, I didn't get that the first time). But I need to choose `AUTHOR.ID` in first combo box instead of `BOOKS.TITLE`. Unfortunately the SQL statement is the same, meaning that a lot of data is coming from the DB for no reason. In my small test the DB return 66 records for only 2 final records. I was using another technique that was doing mostly the same thing before. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: About using SQL directly, check my comment to @Ryan.